# store mass column efficiently using firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on self-project which is an app that store user ingredient they have on the fridge. Currently the database store the item user has as 1 and 0 if they didn't have it. If the user have onion and didn't have garlic. The database will save them as:

garlic : 0

onion : 1

The problem is my app have multiple selection of ingredient that user can choose from and I think its not efficient to save all the ingredient that the app have to the database. Is there any way to efficiently store the only ingredient that user have into database?

Comment: Then only store ingredients that the user has, right?

Comment: make it into an array? @Alex Mamo

Comment: Yes, you can either store them in an array as strings or as [custom objects](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Comment: is there any other reference i can read or view? i read ur document but i cant seems to fully understand it